# from django form uploading a image in windows development server

Tags: django, django-1.3

I have a model like this

```
class Ask(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,  blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="ask/users/avaters", blank=True, )
    question = models.CharField(max_length= 1024)
    ques_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ans_time = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True, auto_now=True)
    display = models.BooleanField()
    asker_ip = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

my forms.py is like this

```
class AskForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length= 500)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    avater = forms.ImageField()
    question = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=1024)
```

my view is like this

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('D:/dsite/ak47/media/ask/users/avaters', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()

def submit_page(request):
    data = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.copy()
        form = AskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ask = Ask()
            ask.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            ask.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            ask.question = form.cleaned_data['question']
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['avater'])
            ask.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ask/')
        else:
            form = AskForm()

    return  render_to_response('ask/index.html', {'form': form,})
```

problem is in my windows development server. When I hit submit it give me a io error. Permission denied. I tried give the folder a full control permission. I'm assuming the error is for other reason. Because I can upload from admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to save file into folder, but did not specified file name.
Your handle function should be:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    save_path = 'D:/dsite/ak47/media/ask/users/avaters'
    destination = open(os.path.join(save_path,f.name), 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

and dont forget add at top of your views.py

```
import os
```

---

### Another solution for this case

Use [ModelForm and it's features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/). [You dont have to handle manually file uploading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files), it's already done by ModelForm. Your *forms.py* should look like this:

```
from .models import Ask


class AskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ask
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'question', 'avater')
```

Your views.py should look like this:

```
def submit_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ask/')
    else:
        form = AskForm()

    return  render_to_response('ask/index.html', {'form': form,})
```

ModelForm will automagically handle all submitted data and create/save new Ask object for it.

Comment: First: Thanks, Image is now uploading. but its not showing on admin can you please tell me how to save it in db.

Comment: Updated answer with refactored code for your case. You're trying to reimplement builtin django features.

Comment: I tried your(@superduper) way before. Just did it again. but Files is not uploading. There is no error though.